# Soundex returns 0 for every character

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, soundex

I have this function which converts a word to a soundex value, but it is returning all letters as 0. My last name, Smith, should by `S530`, but returns `S000`, for example.

Link for code (since it's too long to put on here): http://pastebin.com/9hESxV7P

I had it log the value of `letterArray` and it does evaluate to an array of all the letters in my last name. It has to be something in the `for ... in` loop. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing this line

```
let trimmedWord = word.uppercaseString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
```

it produce S530

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense, since in the `switch` it was using uppercase values. Thanks!